# Finding unique patter of $M$ $1$s in an $N \times N$ matrix, the rest occupied by $0$s

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

I am looking for a solution for a biological problem.
I have a $10 \times 10$ matrix that I need to fill with $10$ molecules.
They can occupy any cell in the matrix (they don't need to be next to each other) but the resulting pattern has to be unique, i.e. cannot be simply rotated or translated into the same pattern. Mirror symmetry is not allowed.
You can consider it a binary problem where the ten molecules are represented by ten $1$s and the rest of the $90$ spaces in the matrix are $0$s. 
As far as I can tell after searching on this site, the answer is a variation of the Polya enumeration but none of the answers give the exact result to my particular problem. 
I started out thinking about this as a simple combinatorial problem of $C(100,10).$ However, that does not take into account the rotational and translational symmetry needed to reduce the number to only the unique patterns the ten molecules/digits can create. 
In more general terms, I am interested in expanding this problem with $M$ molecules within a $N \times N$ matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be simply rotated or translated into the same pattern"? A pattern may be rotatable into itself but cannot be translated into itself. From the rest of the question, it sounds as if you want to count equivalence classes of patterns under rotations and translations?

Comment: Do you want to count all the solutions, or do you just want a method to generate individual solutions that are guaranteed to be asymmetric?

Comment: @joriki: Imagine a 3 x3 matrix where we have three 1s (and also three 0s), the pattern of putting three 1s in the same line or column in this situation could occur only once as a unique solution because every other occurrence could be counted as a rotation or translation of the original pattern.

Comment: Did you mean "and also six $0$s"? (If not, I may be misunderstanding the problem.)

Comment: @nickgard: I know all solutions C(100,10) which is ~ 17 trillion. I need the unique patterns that cannot be rotated or translated into another. Extending the above example in the 10 x 10 matrix there is only one solution for all 1s placed in one line. But it gets complicated when I place the 1s more randomly around.

Comment: @joriki. No, I need to have a certain number of 1s. In the actual example 10 1s and 90 0s in a 10 x 10 matrix.

Comment: @RV66: I don't understand. A $3\times3$ matrix has $9$ entries. If you have three $1$s and three $0$s, that leaves $3$ entries empty, whereas in your question you don't have any empty entries; all $10\cdot10=100$ entries are either $1$ or $0$. So I don't understand how the example in your comment relates to the question.

Comment: Where you say "Mirror symmetry is not allowed", I take it you mean that two patterns that are mirror images of each other (but not related by rotation or translation) count as separate unique patterns?

Comment: @joriki: Sorry, yes. 3 1s and 6 0s. My bad.

Comment: @joriki: Yes, mirror images count as separate patterns if they are not related by rotation or translation.

Comment: Let's stay with the 10 x 10 example because I can work out the 3 x 3 without a problem.

Comment: @RV66 -- It seems you want this: You want an **exact count** of all non-equivalent placements, where two placements are considered equivalent if one is a rotation, reflection, or translation of another, and where (1) rotation is by 90,180,270, (2) reflection is up-down, left-right, or either diagonal, (3) translation is wrap-around.  Am I right?

Comment: @antkam: No, reflection is not counted as a symmetry, see above. Also, I don't see from where you inferred that wrap-around is considered.

Comment: @RV66 -- Better yet: if you can work out the $3 \times 3$ problem, can you show us your result?  I.e. maybe list all the non-equivalent placements?  Very often, when the question's description is unclear, an example would help _everybody_ understand (or guess) what is meant.

Comment: @joriki - sorry, no wrapround.  what was i thinking?  :)  so only the 1s are translated (and the 0s are just fillers)

Answer (score 1):

I'll do this specifically for $M=10$ molecules in an $N\times N$ matrix. Some details depend on the residue of $M\bmod4$, so you'll need to make some small adjustments if you want to use an $M$ with a different residue, but I hope to explain the reasoning sufficiently for you to be able to make those adjustments on your own.

We can deal with translations by counting the number of configurations that fill certain bounding boxes. We can deal with rotations by accounting for rotational symmetry by dividing the counts by appropriate factors.

So let's count the patterns that fill a bounding box of width $w$ and height $h$. There are $wh$ cells in the bounding box, so the basic count of patterns is $\binom{wh}M$. But we mustn't count patterns that don't actually fill the bounding box. That yields $4$ conditions, which we can enforce by inclusion–exclusion.

There are $\binom{w(h-1)}M$ patterns that don't use the top row of the bounding box, another $\binom{w(h-1)}M$ for the bottom row, and then $2\binom{(w-1)h}M$ for the left and right column. There are $4$ pairs of a row and a column, and for each pair there are $\binom{(w-1)(h-1)}M$ patterns that don't use it. There are $\binom{w(h-2)}M$ patterns that use neither the top nor the bottom row, and $\binom{(w-2)h}M$ that use neither the left nor the right column. For three conditions violated simultaneously, the total count is $2\binom{(w-1)(h-2)}+2\binom{(w-2)(h-1)}M$, and for all four conditions simultaneously $\binom{(w-2)(h-2)}M$. (If one of the dimensions is $1$, the corresponding contributions with $-2$ shouldn't be included.) Thus, in total, the number of patterns that fill the entire bounding box is

$$
\binom{wh}M-2\binom{w(h-1)}M-2\binom{(w-1)h}M+4\binom{(w-1)(h-1)}M+\binom{w(h-2)}M+\binom{(w-2)h}M-2\binom{(w-1)(h-2)}M-2\binom{(w-2)(h-1)}M+\binom{(w-2)(h-2)}M\;.
$$

Each of these can be translated to $(N-w+1)(N-h+1)$ different positions. We should only count one quarter of them, since the rest can be generated by rotations through multiples of $\frac\pi2$.

A pattern can only be rotated into itself through $\pi$. (For rectangular bounding boxes, this is true for general $M$, since rotating through $\frac\pi2$ would swap the dimensions of the bounding box. For square bounding boxes this is only true because $M\not\equiv0,1\bmod4$, so there's no way to have $4$-fold symmetry with $M$ molecules.)

To count the patterns that are invariant under a rotation through $\pi$ about the centre of the bounding box, form pairs of cells in the bounding box that are rotated into each other and hence must have the same fill status for the pattern to be invariant. If $w$ and $h$ are both odd, there's one cell in the middle that doesn't get paired. Since $M=10$ is even, this can't be filled in a rotationally invariant pattern. Thus, there are $\binom{\left\lfloor wh/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}$ rotationally invariant patterns. Of these we should count $\frac12$ instead of $\frac14$. But now we also have to figure out how many of these don't actually fill the entire bounding box. An inclusion–exclusion count similar to the one above (but now with only two conditions, due to the rotational symmetry) shows that there are

$$
\binom{\left\lfloor wh/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}-\binom{\left\lfloor w(h-2)/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}-\binom{\left\lfloor(w-2)h/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}+\binom{\left\lfloor (w-2)(h-2)/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}
$$

rotationally invariant patterns that fill the entire bounding box.

Thus, in total we have

$$
\frac14\sum_{w=1}^N\sum_{h=1}^N\left(
\binom{wh}M-2\binom{w(h-1)}M-2\binom{(w-1)h}M+4\binom{(w-1)(h-1)}M+\binom{w(h-2)}M+\binom{(w-2)h}M-2\binom{(w-1)(h-2)}M-2\binom{(w-2)(h-1)}M+\binom{(w-2)(h-2)}M+\binom{\left\lfloor wh/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}-\binom{\left\lfloor w(h-2)/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}-\binom{\left\lfloor(w-2)h/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}+\binom{\left\lfloor (w-2)(h-2)/2\right\rfloor}{M/2}\right)
$$

equivalence classes of patterns under translational and rotational symmetry.

Let's check this for the case $N=2$, which we can easily count by hand. (The next case where it's applicable without adjustment, $N=6$, is already difficult to count by hand.) There's no contribution from $w=h=1$. The remaining terms yield

$$
\frac14\left(2\left(\binom22+\binom11\right)+\binom42-4\binom22+\binom21\right)=2\;,
$$

in agreement with a count by hand.

Comment: I thought about a simplified solution and I want to hear your opinion. There are C(100,10) solutions total (=1.731e13), however not all are unique patterns. Only 1/4 is unique when considering the rotational symmetry. The harder to calculate is the number of patterns that can be translated onto itself. Let's simply that to the following problem: Any pattern that occupies both the upper and lower half of the matrix is unique because we cannot translate it without  leaving the box but patterns that only occupy one half should be calculated once.

Comment: So using the example above we need to take C(50,10) from C(100,10). However, it only amounts to a rounding error so we still have 1.7 x e13 solutions. After dividing it by 4 we end up with 4 x e12 unique patterns.

Comment: Would appreciate if you commented on the above. Thanks.

Comment: @RV66: I don't understand what you mean about the upper and lower half. Did you understand what I wrote about bounding boxes in the answer?

Comment: I think we are thinking along the same lines somewhat differently. What I mean is that I break up the space into to halves. Instead of thinking of a matrix, think of the problem as points occupying a 10 x 10 grid.  I can break them into two adjacent halves (or two equal boxes to use your analogy) with 50 grid points in each half. When we arrange the 10 molecules in the grid some will occupy only one half forming a pattern. If a particular pattern only occupies one half, it can be translated into the same pattern in the other half so should be counted once.

Comment: I am just trying to simplify the translation problem to something that can be easily computed.

Comment: @RV66: This drastically oversimplifies the problem. Please take a look at how I solved it in detail. You'd be miscounting in various ways if you do it like that. You'd only be counting a single translated copy, whereas the number of translated copies depends on the exact width and height of the bounding box of the pattern.

Comment: I think the oversimplification is justified because the smaller box overall means a lot smaller number of potential patterns. Just going from the 10 x 10 box to a 5 x 10 box reduced the overall number of patterns from 1.731e13 to 1e9 patterns. So even though I am miscounting billions, they are ending up being  insignificant in comparison to the overall 17 trillion possible patterns.

Comment: @RV66: Well, if you're not actually interested in the actual count, then of course you can do whatever you want. You didn't indicate that in the question. You said you wanted a particular count.

Comment: I didn't realize it would be so complicated. In the end I need to show to biologists that even 10 molecules on the cell surface can arrange themselves in trillions of unique ways. I do appreciate your answer though! It did encourage me to think of a simpler answer. Your solution becomes more significant when M gets smaller and it also becomes easier to compute so thank you!